# How to define a Dialog for a connector with an array of parameters

Tags: modelica

Let say that I have a connector with a few number parameters (whose number can change). Those parameters are elements of an array.

Would it be possible to have a dialog box to enter each parameter value rather than an array constructor like {1,2,3, ....}?

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear what you mean with entering each parameter in the array.
Modelica does not have a standard mechanism for entering array elements.

Some tools allow you to enter the parameters one by one - e.g. if you do

```
model M "Example model"
  parameter Real r3[:] = zeros(0) "Array parameter";
end M;
```

Then Dymola (standalone and as part of 3D Experience platform) will show a dialog box for M and then a sub-dialog for r3 allowing you to enter each element:
[image: dialog box for r3]

Comment: Thank you very, I could test it in the trial version of dymola and it is a  part of what I would like to implement But I will describe it in another post

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if I understood correctly, but you can use `final` to declare parameters that should not be modified by users. See for example

```
partial model M "Example model"
  parameter Real r1 = 1 "First parameter";
  parameter Real r2 = 2 "Second parameter";
  final parameter Real r[:] = {r1, r2} "Assembled array parameter";
end M;
```

Comment: Thank you, intereting answer. Is it possible to loop thru  r1 ... rN parameters  ? so that I can enter each parameter in the array